# Is there a way to use C++ for iPhone development?

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c, wrapper

Sorry if this is mentioned somewhere, couldn't find any info about it. Post a comment if you find a duplicate.

This is not about whether it's possible at all to compile a C++ program for the iPhone (which I suppose is possible).

Basically the question is, can you bridge between **Objective C** and **C++**?, and if it is possible, would it be feasible to wrap the entire **Cocoa Touch API** for iPhone with a nice C++ library?

I know nothing about Objective C, and I would really like the idea of bringing my current skills in C++ to the iPhone.

**EDIT**: Very similar question [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270455/is-it-possible-to-program-iphone-in-c)

Comment: exact dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270455/is-it-possible-to-program-iphone-in-c

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270455/is-it-possible-to-program-iphone-in-c) is very close to duplicating your own.

However, I would suggest spending a little more time with Objective-C.  I had done C++ development myself before learning Objective-C, and it was a pretty smooth transition.  Many of the core concepts are the same, and all of your base C skills will translate across.  I think that once you get a little ways into it, you'll find that direct Objective-C interaction with the Cocoa frameworks is really the way to go on the Mac and iPhone.  There are many great resources for getting started, like the ones I list [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2009/02/13/resources-getting-started-cocoa).

Admittedly, there are some cases where it's preferred to have a cross-platform C++ engine behind the scenes, and an Objective-C / Cocoa UI.