# Xcode 4 (or 3) iOS, with c++

Tags: c++, ios, xcode4, ios4, xcode3.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to program iPhone in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270455/is-it-possible-to-program-iphone-in-c)

Hello,

I'm sorry I can not find the info that I can program in C++ Xcode4 iPhone 
4th. Is it possible to program in C++ with Xcode4 iPhone4 ? I can not log 
into the Apple forum to ask. Thank you. And as with Xcode 3 on the same issue? Sorry, not the "Newest 'xcode c++ ios' Questions - Stack Overflow" so that I wanted to get a reply soon :)

Comment: You question is quite un-clear. Are you asking whether it's possible to create an iOS application in C++, or merely whether you can use Xcode to write C++ apps in general?

Comment: XCode is an IDE where as iOS is an SDK. You are combining both.

Comment: to create an iOS application in C++ with Xcode 4 or 3.

Comment: I am really curious about whether I really need Xcode 4, if I have the Xcode 3 for programming in Objective-C++ iPhone iOS application? Sorry that I waited so long to my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can code in C++ with both XCode 3 and 4. I definitely suggest going for XCode 4 because of its usability improvements.

Comment: can I create an iOS application in C++ with Xcode 4 or 3?

Comment: Yes, as long as you use Objective-C++ to bridge between normal C++ code. Apple has a tendency to move their documentation around, and the best source I could find was this [page noting that you need to use .mm extensions to reference C++ code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007594)