# iOS iPhone 4th. Xcode 3 or 4

Tags: xcode, ios, ios4, xcode4, iphone-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to program iPhone in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270455/is-it-possible-to-program-iphone-in-c)

iOS iPhone 4th. If I just open the Xcode 3 or 4, and write a program in c++, Xcode compile it and run?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new project by using template but they are Objective-c 
Moreover, unless you have a developer payed account, it will only run on the Iphone Simulator

Comment: You mean in Objective-C++ or Objective-C? I found online, so if I'm writing in c++ code, it will work, as Objective-C++, c++ understands the code, am I right?

Comment: Here something about c++ iphone [link] (http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cpp/c-on-iphone-part-1.html). So I can write and compile c++ code with the iOS SDK in Xcode without Objective-C ?

Comment: Xcode project settings is selected GCC (C/C++ Compiler) version GCC 4.2. Is that mean I can write and run iPhone app in c++ without Objective-C ? In iPhone Simulator of course.

Comment: Everywhere is C++ and Objective-C together mentioned, but not showed just simply C++ for iPhone.

Comment: I actually do not know it you can develop a pure C++ app for iphone. But my guess is that you can't since even the basic stubs to interact with the IOS are Objective-C classes. Anyway don't be afraid for that, it is quite easy to understand and very powerful to use

Comment: I'm just starting to learn c++. Objective-C will leave at leisure