# Can I use c++ file (.cpp and .h) in objective c to build iPhone app?

Tags: objective-c

Let's say. if I have c++ files (.cpp and .h) then can I use those file to create an iPhone app ?

Comment: Short answer is yes. Did you want to know something more specific?

Comment: Yes please...Sample tutorial or any useful references please :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to program iPhone in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270455/is-it-possible-to-program-iphone-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never worked with objective C, but I have talked about this with fellow co-workers who have, and yes you can. I think you have to make objective C interface hooks as to use your c++ code. I am pretty sure you cant exclusively program in C++, but need at least objective C interfaces to call it

hope this shines a bit of hope on it for you
good luck!

people have ported Ogre (open graphics rendering engine) to iOS, and basically the porting developer i think just wrapped all of the C++ with objective C hooks

Also I would be 100% certain that Box2D has been ported and wrapped the same way

Answer (score 0):

short answer is: yes.

for iphone, the primary list of first class languages/dialects are c, objective-c, c++, and objective-c++.