# Is it possible to develop iPhone/iPad apps all in C++ without writing any Objective-C code?

Tags: c++, ios, mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to program iPhone in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270455/is-it-possible-to-program-iphone-in-c)

I'm very familiar with C++ and Java. I know iOS doesn't support Java. But I really don't want to learn another new language Objective-C. So is it possible to develop iPhone/iPad apps all in C++ without writing any Objective-C code? Android development gives you NDK as an option for C++ developers. I don't know if Apple gives a similar C++ SDK completely in C++ only.

Comment: I did it in C, so it's obviously possible in C++ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289890/how-to-write-ios-app-purely-in-c/10290255#10290255

Comment: Android NDK is only for developing certain types of applications, in particular openGL apps. The NDK doesn't give you access to all Android SDK functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the JUCE library.

https://www.juce.com/get-juce/

I build my apps using it, but then I'm mostly interested in audio. Even so, the library is very rich in features and mature. The licenses are reasonably priced too. I am useless with Objective-C, but am able to make highly functional apps purely in C++. Check out the forum on the website and navigate to the iOS section.

Also check out the JUCE tag on stackoverflow

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/juce

..it is a little quiet here, but the main juce forum is quite busy.

Comment: This looks very interesting. I will take a deeper look into it. What versions of iOS and Android does JUCE support so far?