# Using C++ Code in iOS Application

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode4.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to program iPhone in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270455/is-it-possible-to-program-iphone-in-c)

I have an existing C++ code that i want to re-use in iPhone/iPade application (and don't want to have to rewrite it all in Objective C),How can I include this code into my iPhone application?

I tried with Xcode 4.5, but I had several compilation error.

Comment: See e.g. http://philjordan.eu/article/strategies-for-using-c++-in-objective-c-projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a C++ wrapping for a objective-c class recently.
The important thing about separating oc and C++ is that you shouldn't include C++ .h files in oc .h files, and to do this you can use void* pointers.

see:
[Calling Objective-C method from C++ method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061005/calling-objective-c-method-from-c-method)

Answer (score 3):

That should be as simple as this: use the extension `.mm`for all your ObjC files from where you call your C++ code. This will actually make you files handled as Objective-C++ file (which is just the same as Objective-C with the added capability of calling into C++ code).

If you still have errors after doing that, then post the error messages.

Comment: I switch to.mm ,i get this error "'iostream' file not found",when i ran the application

Comment: the question has been closed, but anyway, if you are including iostream from a `.mm` file, then check in your target build settings for that file that the Objective-C++ compiler is also being used. If you just changed the extension to a .m file it might be still treated as a ObjC file.

Answer (score 1):

create .cpp files.

when you create a new file, you can choose to create c++ files.

Also, sergio suggests it right

Comment: This is what I did, and I can not use the method and class C++ file from my .mm ! :(