# Use C++ within iOS project

Tags: c++, objective-c, sdl-2

I'm looking for a solution to create an iOS project with C++.
Do you know if there is other manners than mix C++ with Objective-C ?

It's for a game written in C++, using some librairies : OpenGL, SDL, ...
Do you know if it's possible to use these librairies with an iOS project ?

I found something like this kind of stuff :

http://philjordan.eu/article/mixing-objective-c-c++-and-objective-c++

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to program iPhone in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270455/is-it-possible-to-program-iphone-in-c)

Comment: your google-fu must first be made strong... then you will find your answers...

Answer (score 3):

[On this website](http://www.ciaranmccormack.com/sdl-2-0-on-ios-using-xcode-opengl-es-2-0-and-c-11/) you'll see in a video how to port your SDL game to iOS.

[This link](http://blog.davidecoppola.com/2014/06/how-to-set-up-a-sdl-2-project-for-ios-in-xcode-5/) might be useful too; a step by step  tutorial on how to use SDL.

This is basically it:

1. Create a new iPhone view based application project.
2. Build the SDL libraries statically (libSDL.a and libSDLSimulator.a) for iOS and include them in your project. XCode will ignore the library that is not currently of the correct architecture, hence your app will work both on iPhone and in the iPhone Simulator.
3. Include the SDL header files in your project. (e.g. `#include "SDL.h"`)
4. Remove `AppDelegate.h` and `AppDelegate.m` -- SDL for iPhone provides its own UIApplicationDelegate. Remove your storyboard -- SDL for iPhone produces its user interface programmatically.
5. Delete the contents of `main.m` and program your app as a regular SDL program instead. You may replace `main.m` with your own `main.c`, but you must tell XCode not to use the project prefix file, as it includes Objective-C code.