# Are there open source machine learning libraries that can be integrated with an iOS app (not looking for pros-cons or best/worst libraries)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, machine-learning, data-analysis

I want to do some on-device analysis on data provided by Coremotion. Are there any lightweight machine learning libraries that can be integrated into iOS apps?

Comment: I am just asking for example of open source libraries..not the best library or asking about pros-cons between different libraries.  How will this lead to opinionated answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft open sourced theirs and it's in C++ which you may be able to get to work with that Objective-C++ compiler. Not sure though

heres some details:
http://www.wired.com/2016/01/microsoft-tries-to-one-up-google-in-the-open-source-ai-race/

heres the github:
https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK

heres help on using the C++ in iOS:
[Is it possible to program iPhone in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270455/is-it-possible-to-program-iphone-in-c)